# How to add skew to a normal distribution CDF

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, curve-fitting

I want to curve fit some data to a skewed logistic type distribution. I know that the normal CDF is defined as

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[1 + \text{erf}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right] $$

What I want is to define a similar curve that approaches the upper asymptote slower than it moves away from the lower asymptote, something that I can write in Python. I've heard of the skew normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), but this has a very complicated CDF function. I'm looking to modify the normal CDF equation to give me this type of shape. One thing I thought of was taking the square root of x:

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[1 + \text{erf}\left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right] $$

This way, the erf will take much longer to reach the asymptote, and in order to get to higher values, it will take a much larger $x$. Can anybody tell me if my method is correct/a different method that works easier?

Comment: why not define a piecewise CDF which follows the normal CDF for F(x)<0.5 and follows a heavy tailed CDF for F(x)>0.5 (i.e a t-distribution), or use any one/heavy tail distribution (i.e lognormal).

Comment: A standard method for distributions with positive support is to apply a Box-Cox transformation to the variable (which, to create simpler formulas, is usually re-expressed as a power transformation).  This is the obvious generalization of the square root.  When this operation is done, you wind up with a "generalized" or "power" version of the original distribution.  See Wikipedia on the Generalized Gamma distribution for an example. The problem here, though, is that $x$ can be negative, so you have to take great care in choosing powers that make sense! (The square root is not among them.)

Comment: you could also look into the skew-normal distribution. Search this site!